# passing scope model data to controller

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, multidimensional-array

With angular, I have the following setup on my view:

```
 <div class="sli1"
 ng-init="test=[10,20,30,40,50]"

 <div class="sli2"
 ng-init="test2=[10,20,30,40,50]"
```

I'm trying to pass the ng-init data model back to the controller to pick up as:

```
$scope.data1= $scope.test;
$scope.data2= $scope.test2;
```

Where I use it further down in an array:

```
$scope.sli['test'][0];
$scope.sli['test'][1];
$scope.sli['test'][2];
$scope.sli['test'][3];
```

However not sure what I've missed out.

Comment: test and test2 will already be available in the controller as $scope.test and $scope.test2. So I don't know why you're trying to pick them up and set them in a different scope variable. Doesn't make sense. And what is $scope.sli['test'][0] and that? Could you show a little bit more code for that part? Unclear what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

my suggestion is study more about how angularjs works,initializing data on the view and passing to controller to do process on them is very wrong ,especially if your doing process on the data